# Prove that the derivatives with respect to different independent variables are also independent of each other

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

I don't know if this is a stupid question or not, but how one proves that given two independent variables (x,y), for which:

$$ \frac{\partial x}{\partial y} = 0 $$

For any given function $f(x,y)$ it holds:

$$ \frac{\partial\left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \right)}{\partial\left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \right)} = 0 $$

Furthermore, this holds if I have another function g(x,y) ? That is:

$$ \frac{\partial\left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \right)}{\partial\left( \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} \right)} = 0 $$

I can figure this intuitively, but I would like to have a proof for that, thanks.

Comment: I have no idea what ${\partial\left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \right)}/{\partial\left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \right)}$ even _means_, much less how to show it equals zero.

Comment: I mean the partial derivative of the function $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ respect to the variable $z \equiv \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$

Comment: The problem is that $\partial f/\partial y$ is simply _not_ a variable! Calling it $z$ doesn't change that.

Comment: This question arise by the derivation of the electromagnetic energy-momentum, in which I must compute the term $\frac{\partial( \mathcal{L}_{em} )}{\partial(\partial^{\beta}A^{\alpha})}$, so I'm deriving the lagrangian respect to a derivative. But this leads to a result, so I'm trying to understand what is this object.

Comment: If that question makes sense it is because it's clear from the context what _set of variables_ you're talking about...

Comment: The set of variables are $x^{\alpha} = ( x,y,z,ict ) $, the symbol $\partial^{\beta} = (\nabla, \frac{i}{c} \frac{\partial }{\partial t} ) $ is the four-gradient and $A^{\alpha} = (\vec{A}, \frac{i \varphi}{c}) $ the four potential in which each component is function of the set of variables $x^{\alpha}$. So I could have: $$ \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \left( \frac{\partial A_y}{\partial x} \right)} $$ So what this object means if you say that this can't be considered a variable for the derivation ?

Comment: For that expression to make sense you need to specify a set of variables _including_ $\partial^\beta A^\alpha$. Read the answer I posted.

Comment: Ok, I understand, now I will try to think what this means physically, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is meaningless, because the notion of the partial derivative of a function with respect to another function is undefined. Calling the second function a variable doesn't change that.

For example: Say $f=x-y$, and set $z=x+y$. What would $\partial f/\partial z$ be? On the one hand, $$f=z-2y,$$which would appear to indicate that $$\partial f/\partial z=1.$$On the other hand, $$f=2x-z,$$which seems to show that $$\partial f/\partial z=-1.$$

If you want to talk about $\partial f/\partial z$ you need to explain which of those two calculations is correct, and why the other one is wrong. They look sort of the same...

(To make sense of the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to a variable that variable has to be part of a complete *set* of independent variables; the partial derivative is defined in terms of holding the other variables constant, which is meaningless until we say what the "other variables" *are*.

For example, the first calculation of $\partial f/\partial z$ is correct *if* we're considering the two variables $y,z$, while the second is correct *if* we're considering the two variables $x,z$.)